# save images locally - canvas

Tags: java, image, inputstream, bufferedinputstream

The code right down to this saving photos from a HTML page is working.

```
        String 
                nameimage, 
                srcfoto;

        nameimage    =   vs.getValor("NAMEIMAGE");
        srcfoto     =   vs.getValor("img").toString();

        URL url = new URL(srcfoto);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\img\\ " + nameimage + ".png"); 
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();

        vs.setReturnOK("Image save!");
        return vs.getReturnOK();
```

My problem is that I need to download the following canvas src..

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Only by accepting this src, example /image.png and don't data:image

In debug...

[image]

I was reading a bit on this question but did not understand, and do not know if this is the problem [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

any help is welcome...